# Musixtex setting eighth rest for Cajon Drum Score

Tags: musixtex, musixper

It is needed to adjust the vertical aligment for eighth rest for Cajon Drum Score, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\begin{document}
    
\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{PuenteFestejo}{a qui va-mos va-mos va-mos}%hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-3mm}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{12}8} %Compás en 12/8
    \setlines{1}{2}
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% g k
    \A\assignlyrics1{PuenteFestejo}% added to place handindication
    \Notes\zcharnote{-10}{\A \hspace*{-0.15cm} un}\ds\ibl0g0\qb0{g}\tbl0\qb0{g}\cu k\qu k\hsk\cl g\ql g\hsk\cu k\qu k\en%
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}
        
\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The expected output should be as follow:
[image: expected]

Comment: In this case, page 37 of the manual (Musixtex.pdf) gives the answer, adapted to the distance you need: \raise-1\Interligne\ds. Be aware that your text 'un' does not line up with the rest, it comes closer with \zsong instead of \zcharnote.

Comment: Great, it works perfectly. Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\begin{document}
    
\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{PuenteFestejo}{a qui va-mos va-mos va-mos}%hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-3mm}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{12}8} %Compás en 12/8
    \setlines{1}{2}
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% g k
    \A\assignlyrics1{PuenteFestejo}% added to place handindication
    \Notes\zsong{\A \hspace*{-0.15cm} un}\raise-2\Interligne\ds\ibl0g0\qb0{g}\tbl0\qb0{g}\cu k\qu k\hsk\cl g\ql g\hsk\cu k\qu k\en%
    \Endpiece
 \end{music}
        
\end{document}
```

The solved output is as follow:
[image: solved]